# get data from a json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to get the data from a json. I have the idea of a loop to access all levels.
I have only been able to pull data from a single block.

```
print(output['body']['data'][0]['list'][0]['outUcastPkts'])
```

How do I get the other data?

```
import json,urllib.request

data = urllib.request.urlopen("http://172.0.0.0/statistic").read()
output = json.loads(data)

for elt in output['body']['data']:
    print(output['body']['data'][0]['inUcastPktsAll'])
    for elt in output['list']:
        print(output['body']['data'][0]['list'][0]['outUcastPkts'])
```

```
{
  "body": {
    "data": [
      {    
        "inUcastPktsAll": 3100617019,
        "inMcastPktsAll": 7567,
        "inBcastPktsAll": 8872,
        "outPktsAll": 8585575441,
        "outUcastPktsAll": 8220240108,
        "outMcastPktsAll": 286184143,
        "outBcastPktsAll": 79151190,
        "list": [
          {
            "outUcastPkts": 117427359,
            "outMcastPkts": 1990586,
            "outBcastPkts": 246120
          },
          {
            "outUcastPkts": 0,
            "outMcastPkts": 0,
            "outBcastPkts": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "inUcastPktsAll": 8269483865,
        "inMcastPktsAll": 2405765,
        "inBcastPktsAll": 124466,
        "outPktsAll": 3101194852,
        "outUcastPktsAll": 3101012296,
        "outMcastPktsAll": 173409,
        "outBcastPktsAll": 9147,
        "list": [
          {
            "outUcastPkts": 3101012296,
            "outMcastPkts": 90488,
            "outBcastPkts": 9147
          },
          {
            "outUcastPkts": 0,
            "outMcastPkts": 0,
            "outBcastPkts": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "msgs": [ "successful" ]
  },
  "header": {
    "opCode": "1",
    "token": "",
    "state": "",
    "version": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by other data?

Answer (score 1):

```
output = json.loads(data)              #Type of output is a dictionary.
                                       #Try to use ".get()" method.
print(output.get('body'))              #Get values of key 'body'
print(output.get('body').get('data'))  #Get a list of key 'data'
```

If a key doesn't exist, the '.get()' method will return None.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Answer (score 0):

In python you can easily iterate over the objects of a list like so:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 7]
>>> for elem in l:
...     print(elem)
...
1
2
3
7
```

This works regarding what can of object do you have in the list (integers, tuples, dictionaries). Having that in mind, your solution was not far off, you only to do the following changes:

```py
for entry in output['body']['data']:
    print(entry['inUcastPktsAll'])
    for list_element in entry['list']:
        print(list_element['outUcastPkts'])
```

This will give you the following for the json object you have provided:

```py
3100617019
117427359
0
8269483865
3101012296
0
```